# Is there a delay between mapping a crawled property?

Tags: managed-property

After I map a crawled property, is the Managed Property immediately available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, all items must be recrawled for the mapping to take effect for that item.

Comment: Thanks.  Looking forward to this mapped property showing up in my Item Display Template.  Cheers!

Comment: Hey Trevor, I'm still not seeing the managed property in my display template.  Unfortunately I don't have access to the crawler.  Is there anyway to tell if the crawl occurred.  I went into the advanced setting for the document library and clicked Reindex Document Library to make sure it was a full crawl.  Thanks.